# Is it possible to "cast" desktop/workspaces to another Ubuntu machine over local wifi network?

Tags: wireless, remote-desktop

On my local network I have my main computer which dual boots Ubuntu and Windows 10 and I would like to 'cast' the screen to my (less powerful) Ubuntu laptop and to be able to control it over wifi while still at home (ie from the couch rather sitting in the office).

I imagine this is something quite a few people would want to do so I'm assuming/hoping that something exists?

Comment: Just want to clarify your aim. Do you want to be able to control the main system via the other laptop or do you just want the screen to be viewed from the other laptop

Comment: Thanks for asking - I'll update the question. I want to be able to control the main system

Comment: Is [Remote Desktop/VNC](http://askubuntu.com/questions/155477/how-do-i-remotely-control-another-ubuntu-desktop-from-ubuntu?rq=1) what you're looking for? Teamviewer is another option that works regardless of whether you're on the local network or not.

Comment: Thank you @PatrickNegus - exactly what I was hoping for! I will try it this evening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu has a built in Remote Desktop application that can be used to control PCs over your local network. Simply allow your computer to be controlled (allow other users to view your desktop), set a password (optional), and select the correct protocol:

- `VNC` for Ubuntu-to-Ubuntu
- `RDP` for Ubuntu-Windows

Simply open up Remote Desktop on your second computer, type in the specified IP (ex: 192.128.1.1), and you should be good to go.

If you wish to control your desktop from another network other than your own, programs such as [Teamviewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/) make it really easy.