# How to access the Linux machine remotly?

Tags: software-installation, remote-access

How can i access the Linux machine remotely ? That means i want to access my friend laptop which is booted with ubuntu16.04, and my laptop also booted with ubuntu16.04.
what and all softwares i want install and send the procedure too

Comment: Your question is very broad.  Do you want to share files, have terminal access, use databases on each other's PC, manage your friend's PC?  Could you clarify?

Comment: There are several ways to remotely access a machine, each having their own pros and cons. It all depends on what you plan to do. Are you going to be just transferring files, or did you need full UI access, or just command line access or?

Comment: Check out the answers in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155477/how-do-i-remotely-control-another-ubuntu-desktop-from-ubuntu?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you would like to access your friends machine via GUI. Just install TeamViewer (Internet Must) on both machines. Then you required Teamviewer ID and password from your friends machine, then you can access your friends machine remotely with GUI.
2. If both computers are not connected to the Internet but are connected to LAN, you can enable the remote desktop of the machine and access the machine remotely. [Info to enable](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/07/remote-access-ubuntu-16-04/)
3. If you want to access only the command line, you must install openssh-server on both machines, and then you will be able to access the command line. (LAN, Disable firewall must)