# How do I remotely control an Ubuntu GUI session from behind a NAT?

Tags: networking, vnc, rdp, remmina, nat

Of course I can use Remmina and the like, as [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155477/). But both the source and target  Ubuntu laptops are behind their own routers (NAT). I am not able to configure port forwarding.

Some sort of third-party is needed, perhaps; then both sides would connect to it. Are there services that do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeamViewer should do the job: www.teamviewer.com