# About remotely control another Ubuntu desktop from Ubuntu without needs its IP

Tags: networking, remote-desktop

I need to control one PC (Ubuntu OS) with long distance, so now I am using the [AnyDesk](https://anydesk.com/en) app but for controlling the PC needs to **confirm the new request**.

So I have tried the Remmina by this post instruction :

[How do I remotely control another Ubuntu desktop from Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155477/how-do-i-remotely-control-another-ubuntu-desktop-from-ubuntu)

But as the target PC'IP change (dynamic IP), it is hard for me to get the target PC IP and add it on the Remmina app.

So I asked here to find some method for remote controlling the Ubuntu PC without needs to have its IP and no needs to confirm request for every time.

Thanks.

Comment: TeamViewer? its free for personal use and supports Ubuntu (from my experience with pop os)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with anydesk.On the remote computer (the server) first go to set password for unattended access and then go to settings --> security --> allow unattended access

[image]